# data structure to get one object parameter by another

Tags: python, data-structures

We have a set of commodities. Each of them has an ID, link, and price. We need to be able to quickly get link by ID and price by link. One of the solutions is to store 2 dictionaries: {id: link} and {link: price}, but is there a better solution?

Comment: It might depend on what you mean by "better". Is there some aspect of the multiple dict solution that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: If the relationship (id -> link -> price) is unique, why not have a {id:price} dictionary?

Comment: {id:price} dictionary will not allow to get link by id. In my case it's easy to get ID by link, but otherwise it would be also hard to get price by link, so it does not meet both the conditions.

Comment: do you really have to get them separatelly ? if you have to get `link` and `price` at the same time (starting with the same ID) then `{id: [link, price]}` but if sometimes you have to get `link` by `ID` and sometimes `price` by `link` then it may need separated dictionares. But if yiu keep it in database then it has no matter because you can create query which `SELECT link ... WHERE id=ID` or `SELECT price ... WHERE link="http://..."`